# Let devise understand custom request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I have an rails app, and customized devise views to add them some interactivity with angular. So, my inputs look like

```
<input id="user_name" name="name" ng-blur="isNameBusy()" type="text">
```

(all unnecessary atributtes are omitted)

It means that request while sending form would look like:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "name"=>"test", "email"=>"test@mail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

but devise doesn't understand this request, cause by default inputs in devise views have name attribute like:

```
<input id="user_name" name="user[name]" ng-blur="isNameBusy()" type="text">
<input id="user_email" name="user[email]"  type="email">
```

And request look like:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "user"=>{"name"=>"test", "email"=>"test@mail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

You see, fields are wrapped in **user** key.

Of course, I can use default devise names in my js, like

```
 registerForm.user[name].$valid
```

But it looks so ugly!
How let devise understand my request?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the name attributes of your input field, something like this:

```
<input id="user_name" name="user[name]" ng-blur="isNameBusy()" type="text">
```

You must override the default Devise controller that you can find the master here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb

Then modify it accordly of your custom params.

This answer is only dedicated if you want to manage the session, otherwise a "classic" controller of the user model is ok (for example to create a new user).

Comment: Yep, sessions/ register controller.
I know about overriding devise controllers, but have no idea about how let him take my parameters without **user** key. That is the problem

Comment: @justso your form is for creating a new user or for a log in?

Comment: The form above is for login, but I have the same issue for registration form also.